# Simplecart beforecheckout Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simplecart installed and i need to save in a db all the article in the cart.
So I thought something like this

```
  simpleCart.bind( "beforeCheckout" , function( data ){
       $.post("shopping/saveMe",function(hmtl){ alert(""); }, "html");
  });
```

The problem seems that `beforecheckout` doesn't wait for the ajax to finish or even start.
I only know that if i put a simple `alert()` after the post. It works fine. Any idea how to solve this problem? Because obviously I don't need  the alert XD.

Comment: So you're replacing the checkout process with AJAX?

Comment: no i need to create the invoice before is redirect to paypal...and add the custom field with the id of the last generated invoice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys, i found a solution....  for those who can have the same problem.. actually the solution is pretty simple.... don't use the $.post but instead the classi $.ajax and then set async to false... in that way beforecheckout will wait for the call to finish :D